# Why the C++ target is 6X slower than the Java target

Tags: antlr4

I have now  2 significant examples that shows the following runtime:

```
               Java    C++  FileSize    Slowdown C++/Java
Example1:       85s   533s   2528699       6.2x
Example2:       64s   246s   1031993       3.8x
```

I'm sure my grammar has issues (separate problem I am starting to address), but what could be the possible reason for the slowness of C++ compare to the Java implementation? All the C++ code (Java runtime, the generated parser) is compiled with -O2 on a Linux machine.
Same machine, same grammar, same example files were used. I made sure I only compare the parsing time. Walking the AST takes 1 second anyway.

Thanks
Alain

Comment: Have you run the parse step at least twice in a row? There is a warmup phase which is significantly slower than following parse runs.

Comment: I can't in my application, I have to process files "cold", I need to start a fresh parser per file. Are you saying the warmup is heavier in the C++ implementation vs the Java implementation? How do you account for the difference?

Comment: Let me add some precision: in the same execution (runtime), I launch multiple threads that parse bits and pieces of files, I new and delete instances of the lexers and parsers, but I guess the learning is cached in some global (static) data structure and does not rely on keeping the parsers around? I am precompiling some large files (packages) in single thread and persist the AST on disk, those are the examples I am pointing to, when I do this, it is in different runtime so each starts cold. This is were I see the more drastic diff in between the C++ and Java parser.

Comment: Yes, the warmup is required to build some shared static structures (the DFA with ATN configs). This requires more time in C++, because of the require `shared_ptr`, which is relatively slow. Once the data is cached, you can create and delete as many parsers as you like. They all use that shared data.

Comment: I guess we will have to wait for C++20: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf

Comment: I have a bigger question, what was the rationale for making the cache static? Why not make it an object passed to the parsers? and don't use the shared_ptr at all, make the system truly thread independent.

Comment: In my use case, each thread parses many files, but I compute initially a load balancing by file size (and/or break into file chunks) that pretty much guaranties all threads will finish almost at the same time. Within a thread I see the usefulness of sharing a cache. But in between thread, not really (Maybe for memory). What would it take to make a change like that?

Comment: Also, Is there a way to save/restore DFA?